# Group by error with calculation in select

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a question.

This is the query :

```
SELECT a.naam as "Artiest", SUM(o.numberOfOrders) as "Aantal singles",   
(SUM(o.numberOfOrders) * s.price) * 0.35 as "Winst  

FROM orders o
JOIN singles s ON s.singleid = b.singleid
JOIN artist a ON a.artistid = s.artistid
WHERE b.date= TO_DATE('15/MAY/2012','dd/mon/yyyy')
GROUP BY a.name
```

When I execute this query I get the error :

> "not a GROUP BY expression"

I've already tried putting **(SUM(o.numberOfOrders) * s.price) * 0.35** in the group by as well,
but then I get the error:

> "group function is not allowed here"

How do I fix this?

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? Sql Server, MySQL?

Comment: Also, make sure your group by column is the same as what's in the select. I notice that you're selecting `a.naam` and grouping by `a.name`. Any column that's in the select that isn't in an aggregation should be in your group by clause.

Comment: You have defined both `a` and `s` ,but am unable to find `b`

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't the full query, as there are numerous mistakes that are probably due to building the query in SO instead of a straight copy/paste. If neither of these answers are a solution to your problem, can you please provide some additional information (structure of tables, missing `b` reference, any additional context, etc).

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistakes while copying my query. I wanted to translate the tablenames to english to make it easier to understand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to replace this with one of the following:

```
sum(o.numberOfOrders*s.price)*0.35
```

or:

```
sum(o.numberOfOrdrs)*avg(s.price)*0.35
```

or (maybe):

```
sum(o.numberOfOrdrs)*max(s.price)*0.35
```

In other words, s.price is not in the group by

Comment: This answer is more correct than mine. +1. He is also missing some double-quotes in his query though.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a doublequote. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.naam as "Artiest", 
    SUM(o.numberOfOrders) as "Aantal singles",   
    (SUM(o.numberOfOrders) * s.price) * 0.35 as "Winst"
FROM 
    orders o
        JOIN singles s ON s.singleid = b.singleid
        JOIN artist a ON a.artistid = s.artistid
WHERE 
    b.date= TO_DATE('15/MAY/2012','dd/mon/yyyy')
GROUP BY a.name
```